# If I add the same row to database 999999 times, does the sql engine recognize it?

Tags: sql-server-express

I use sql server express 2012. If I add  the same row to database 999999 times does the sql engine recgonize it and not
add this data 99999 times because its the same data and under the hood
it just save the id and point the first record to save space?

Answer (score 0):

It depends as to how you have defined your table structure. If there is a primary key or unique(*which does not appear to be present as per your statement*) key then it will not allow. Else it will store all the data in the table. *Also it does not make sense to store that huge amount of duplicates in your table.* :)

Also check [this](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/practicalsqldba/2013/03/21/sql-server-part-6-design-consideration-of-clustered-index/):

> SQL server will allow you to create a clustered index on non unique
>   column, but uniqueness is one of the most desirable attribute for any
>   indexes especially for a clustered index.Even if SQL server allow to
>   create clustered index on a non unique column , internally SQL server
>   add 4 bytes value for all duplicate instance of clustered key and this
>   4 bytes variable length column is known as uniquiifier .In this case
>   SQL server consider the clustered key as the combination of non unique
>   column on which clustered index is defined and internally generated
>   uniquifier column.This value will be stored where ever the clustered
>   key to be stored.